# Bluetooth Low Energy on iOS 6; CBPeripheralManagerDelegate

Tags: ios, ios6, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I came to know that iOS 6 can be made as a broadcaster. i.e. `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate`.

Where can I find reference documentation for `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate`?, I don't see in on Apple's site. Does that mean still it is under development?.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question to the Apple Bluetooth engineers themselves at: Bluetooth-dev@lists.apple.com

Comment: Have you watched the Core Bluetooth sessions from WWDC 2012 (sessions 703 and 705)? They might be able to answer some of your questions.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately CBPeripheralManager it is still not in the official Apple documentation yet but the framework is there to use and you can read the detailed CBPeripheralManager comments directly from the CoreBluetooth.framework header files in XCode.

I would recommend checking out the app [LighBlue](http://blog.punchthrough.com/post/34242179806/simulate-ble-peripherals-with-lightblue-1-2) if you want an easy way to play around with iOS acting as a peripheral.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, there seems to be a bug in iOS 6 pertaining to BLE UUID Generation. It's been affecting several developers including myself.

http://e2e.ti.com/support/low_power_rf/f/538/t/216046.aspx